# PySpark accessing glue data catalog

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am having trouble being able to accessing a table in the Glue Data Catalog using pySpark in Hue/Zeppelin on EMR. I have tried both emr-5.13.0 and emr-5.12.1.

I tried following https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/data_cleaning_and_lambda.md
but when trying to import the GlueContext it errors saying `No module named awsglue.context.`

Another note is that when doing a `spark.sql("SHOW TABLES").show()` it comes up empty for Hue/Zeppelin but when using the pyspark shell on the master node I am able to see and query the table from the Glue Data Catalog.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I spent some time to simulate the issue, so I spinned up an EMR, with "Use AWS Glue Data Catalog for table metadata" enabled. After enabling web connections, and in zeppelin I issued a show databases command, and it worked fine.  Please find herewith the command & output from Zeppelin:

```
%spark
spark.sql("show databases").show

+-------------------+
|airlines-historical|
|            default|
|      glue-poc-tpch|
|     legislator-new|
|        legislators|
|      nursinghomedb|
| nycitytaxianalysis|
| ohare-airport-2006|
|           payments|
|              s100g|
|                s1g|
|           sampledb|
|             testdb|
|               tpch|
|           tpch_orc|
|       tpch_parquet|
+-------------------+
```

As far as your other issue of "**No module named awsglue.context**", I think it may not be possible with an EMR commissioned Zeppelin.  I think the only way, an awsglue.context can be accessed / used, is via a Glue Devendpoint that you may need to set up in AWS Glue, and then, use an glue jupyter notebook or a locally setup Zeppelin notebook connected to glue development endpoint.

Am not sure if glue context can be directly accessed from an EMR commissioned Zeppelin notebook, maybe am wrong.

You can still access the glue catalog, since EMR provides you with an option for the same, so you can access the databases and do your ETL jobs.

Thanks.

Comment: Totally weird I just gave this another go on Zeppelin and I was able to query the Glue Data Catalog this time :).

Thanks for the information!

Comment: Glad, it is working now with re-attempt, did you try getting glue context object in the EMR Zeppelin? Is it working out-of-the box?  Please update

Comment: I'm using Glue Dev endpoint with Zeppelin installed in my local machine, I can access Glue catalog from scala and python api but not with %sql or spark.sql() both returns only default database.. any help?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below function to check the availability of databases in glue

```
def isDatabasePresent(database_name):
    """
        check if the glue database exists
        :return: Boolean
    """
    client = get_glue_client()
    responseGetDatabases = client.get_databases()
    databaseList = responseGetDatabases['DatabaseList']
    for databaseDict in databaseList:
        if database_name == databaseDict['Name']:
            return True
```

Comment: Where is get_glue_client defined and what is it's definition?

Answer (score -1):

Please check out the details in this link from AWS, and see if the EMR is configured correctly as recommended ([Configure Glue Catalog in EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html)).  Also ensure that appropriate permissions are granted to access AWS Glue catalog. Details are in the attached link.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, looks like the Glue support for EMR is available from emr-5.8.0 or later.  May be that's a reason it is failing for you, and I suggest you please try with 5.8.0, and follow all configuration as per the link.  Thanks.

Comment: I followed this when setting up my cluster, I checked both Hive and Spark to use Glue as their metastore. I also checked the configuration settings to make sure it was set properly. As for the version of emr, the two I have tried are the latest versions which are much newer then 5.8.0 (5.13.0 and 5.12.1)